# error accessing filenames on bash loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh

I'm programming a bash file that iterates through a directory running certain command using the relative path of files inside it.

```
#the inputCSV is a path, that the user introduces, i'm currently passing '.'

inputCSV="." 
for loopVar in $inputCSV"/*.csv"
do 
    echo "Dir result: "
    dir
    echo "inputCSV contains: "$inputCSV
    echo "This should be a filename but is: "$loopVar
done
unset input
```

The `dir` command shows that, effectively there are files on the directory, and the inputCSV have `.`  in it, but the `loopVar` is equal to the concatenation and doesn't iterate throug the directory. This is my console output:

```
Dir result: 
Ejemplo.csv batch.sh sqlFolder
inputCSV contains .
This should be a filename but is: ./*.csv
```

Im using `Linux version 3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jul 25 05:07:12 UTC 2014`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted wildcards aren't expanded by the shell. On the other hand, it's good to quote variables to prevent word splitting on them if they contain whitespace:

```
for loopVar in "$inputCSV"/*.csv
```